# ESLint: Mixed spaces and tabs. (no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

When I reformatting my code with **ctrl + alt + L** in WebStorm I see this error ESLint: Mixed spaces and tabs. (no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs)[Eslint error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmDB7.png)

I again install eslint add settings for eslint in Tabs Indents add Tab sizes 2 Indet 2 Continuation indent 2 and add prettier [Tabs and Indents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW0Py.png)

here is my eslint configuration [esling configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/613rU.png)

WebStorm settings [WebStorm settings Eslint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFkU6.png)

Please help how I can reformatting my code no errors

Comment: You should change your ESLint configuration to set `"no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": "smart-tabs"`, but I don’t know how you’re configuring ESLint so it’s hard to be more specific than that.

Comment: "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": "smart-tabs" after add this in my eslint.json rules I again see the same error in my application

Comment: What about the WebStorm settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question when I reformat my code with **Ctrl + Alt + L**. this is a WebStorm refactoring not an Eslint one and that's why I see the Eslint error. So, now I install this plugin `**@stylistic/eslint-plugin-js**`, from this website https://eslint.style/packages/js#install and configure my **eslint.json** file as shown on the website and after configure **eslint.json/js** file you can easly reformatting your code.

For my case, in my **eslint.json** file, it work's like this.

```
"plugins": [
"react",
"@typescript-eslint",
"@stylistic/js"
],
"rules": {
"@stylistic/js/indent": ["error", 2]
}
```